# A combobox extracts a code from event.target.value: it shouldn't, a code isn't replaced by a label when expected. I'm not doing things the proper way

Tags: angular, combobox

I have an application that works but shouldn't. And I would like starting correcting it.
I believe I have done things that clashes one against another, because my knowledge of *Angular* is low.

1. By a REST service, *Angular* receives `Commune` (City) objects, with their name, population, city code, etc.

```
/** Une commune du Code Officiel Géographique */
export interface Commune { 
    /** Code de la commune */
    codeCommune: string;

    /** Nom de la commune */
    nomCommune: string;

    /** Population totale de la commune. */
    population: number;

    /** Surface de la commune, en hectares. N\'est pas alimenté pour les arrondissements. */
    surface?: number | null;
    [...]
}
```

[image]

I'm displaying and offer to select a value by this combo-box:

```html
<input type="text" list="communesCOG" [(ngModel)]="libelleCommuneSelectionnee" (change)="selectCommune($event.target.value)" placeholder="Tapez le nom de la commune">
<datalist id="communesCOG" >
    <option *ngFor="let commune of communes" [value]="commune.codeCommune">{{commune.nomCommune}} ({{commune.nomDepartement}})</option>
</datalist>
```

It doesn't stop my application, but my IDE is already complaining about that:

[image]

`selectCommune($event.target.value)`, with `value` in red, that isn't recognized.

What surprises me, is that it is working: the code `55001` enters my function:
(where `communesMap` is a `communesMap: Map<string, Commune> = new Map<string, Commune>()` loaded with all the French cities, and indexed by their city code).

[image]

but there's no `value` property for an `Event.target`... What should have done, here?

2. If I select a value in that list, I'm expecting a formatted result shown in that combobox, as I do not wish the user to see the city code that won't mind anything to him.

But at the time I'm doing the selection, and until I leave the field, it only displays the city code:

[image]

3. And then, the focus left, displays the wished description:
   *Abainville (Meuse) 300 hab.*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `[(ngModel)]` on your input. Do not subscribe to `(change)` event, but to `(ngModelChange)` instead, where `$event` is the new value:

```
<input type="text" list="communesCOG" [(ngModel)]="libelleCommuneSelectionnee" (ngModelChange)="selectCommune($event)" placeholder="Tapez le nom de la commune">
```

Comment: It corrected both troubles at the same time! Great!